# Bash - How can I archive and compress files in subdirectories but only with a certain filename

Tags: linux, bash, gzip, tar

I have a directory structure that looks like:

```
main_directory/
    directory1:
        sub_directory1:
            files:
                myfile.txt
                otherfile.txt
        sub_directory2:
            files:
                myfile.txt
                otherfile.txt
        sub_directory3:
            files:
                myfile.txt
                otherfile.txt
        sub_directory4:
            files:
                myfile.txt
                otherfile.txt
    directory2:
        sub_directory1:
            files:
                myfile.txt
                otherfile.txt
        sub_directory2:
            files:
                myfile.txt
                otherfile.txt
        sub_directory3:
            files:
                myfile.txt
                otherfile.txt
        sub_directory4:
            files:
                myfile.txt
                otherfile.txt
```

I am trying to figure out (by trial and error because I'm not an expert at Linux) how to only gzip the `myfile.txt` files in all the directories. Since they all have the same filename in different paths (there was no way around this), I need to be able to keep the files path in the archive as well. So the final gzipped tar file I am looking to create would have the contents:

```
mytar.tar.gz
    main_directory/directory1/sub_directory1/files/myfile.txt
    main_directory/directory1/sub_directory2/files/myfile.txt
    main_directory/directory1/sub_directory3/files/myfile.txt
    main_directory/directory1/sub_directory4/files/myfile.txt
    main_directory/directory2/sub_directory1/files/myfile.txt
    main_directory/directory3/sub_directory2/files/myfile.txt
    main_directory/directory4/sub_directory3/files/myfile.txt
    main_directory/directory5/sub_directory4/files/myfile.txt
```

Is there a simple `bash` way to do this? I suppose I could write a `python` script to do it, but that seems overkill.

Does anyone have any advice?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This overcame this issue described in the other answer.

```
find main_directory/ -name "myfile.txt" | tar -czvf mytar.tar.gz -T -
```

Answer (score 2):

Assuming there are not too many files, you can do something like:

```
cd main_directory/..
find main_directory -name "myfile.txt" | xargs tar zcf mytar.tar.gz
```

In the event that there are a lot of files, you can pipe the file list into a file/stream and pass that into tar.

```
find main_directory -name "myfile.txt" -print0 | tar zcf myar.tar.gz --null -T -
```

This prints out the filenames separated by nulls (`-print0` to `find`) and instructs `tar` to parse that correctly from `stdin`; using nulls ensures that any special characters in directories are handled properly

Comment: Awesome. Thanks! This is perfect. I think I need to learn about pipes a bit more :-)

Comment: This is going to blow up badly if the number of files gets too large for xargs to construct a command line since it will run the `tar` multiple times and overwrite itself (or fail). It might be better to use the `-T` argument to tar to tell it to get the list of files to archive from a file and tell it to use `/dev/stdin` or similar (or just write to a file and then pass that to `tar`.

Comment: Yup, just ran into this. Sorry for the premature response...it looked like it was working fantastically. I guess I had too many files (about 1000). Only a handful of them were actually included in the final tar.

Comment: I see you figured out `-T`; updated my answer to include that and a trick around handling newline or nulls or other special characters in filenames.

Answer (score 0):

With a new enough (4.0.0+ I believe) version of bash (and a number of other shells) the following will work:

```
tar -czf mytar.tar.gz main_directory/**/myfile.txt
```

Comment: It will work if `globstar` (and `dotglob`) is on, but it will still hit `ARG_MAX` and fail on a large number of files.

Comment: Indeed. I meant to mention `globstar` but managed to forget. And yes, command line length issues are still going to be a problem but the failure here is not as bad as the one in @EmilSit's case as it does not end up with a truncated (but apparently complete) tarball (or an error well into the tar process) and instead errors immediately.

Answer (score 0):

If the directory structure is indeed this regular, the wildcard

```
main_directory/*/*/files/myfile.txt
```

will match the files you want.  However, if there are many files, you may need to revert to `find` / `xargs` in order to avoid the "argument list too long" (`ARG_MAX`) problem.

If there are files named `myfile.txt` which you do not want to include because their path does not match the wildcard exactly, there are certainly ways to exclude them from `find`, too; perhaps then this additional constraint should be stated in the question.